# How can i send multiple files as array of objects to node.js server from angular app?

Tags: angular

I have an `angular` app in which i have to send multiple `files` as array of objects in `formData`. So i don't have any idea that how can i send that. I am having a multiple records in a table and user can add new row on clicking on "Add" button in the table and then user can fill details in that row. And each row has it's own 2 attachments like this

[image]

See above attached image that i have a rows in table and each record have it's own `Cnic Picture Front` and `Cnic Picture Back` so i have to send attachments in `formData` like this

```
cnicDetails : 
  [{cnicFront: // ..uploaded file.. //, cnicBack: // ..uploaded file //}, {cnicFront: // 
   ..uploaded file.. //, cnicBack: // ..uploaded file //
  }]
```

So how can i send `files` to `server` in this pattern using `angular9`?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can achieve this using `interface`, `formData` & `array`.

1. Create an `interface` with possible and optional values.
2. Create an `array` of type interface
3. when the user adds a new record and clicks on `save` push that record into the array
4. and then send `array` in `formData`

You can also do this way to append formData on each `Save` button click

```
let formData = new FormData()
formData.append() //append formData and send final data to server
```

Comment: cab you refer any example of this?

Comment: answer updated if you still need more help please create `stackblitz` and if my answer is helpful accept it.

Comment: but i can't send array of objects in `formData.set` funciton...

Comment: Please create `stackblitz` i can help. thanks